# Opening a php url from python without opening the browser

Tags: php, python

I have a PHP script that is located in a remote location - http://myremoteserver.net/myCode.php - that I want to run from inside my python code.

I am using the below, and it runs very well, but the downside is that it opens the default browser. Is there a way I can do this without the browser opening?

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://myremoteserver.net/myCode.php')
```

Comment: If you don't care about js you can use `urllib`

Comment: I believe this is a XY problem

Comment: Please read the official document of [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) carefully, it tell you the usage and meaning of it whose purpose is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

res = requests.get("http://myremoteserver.net/myCode.php")
page = res.text
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the requests module to perform an http request on that url.  You just just need to install the package with pip.

Install the package with pip

```
pip install requests
```

Sample calling a get request

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://testing/test.php")
```